# Create and copy a table from one SQL database to another

Tags: sql, oracle, crud

Let's say I have a production database and a development database.

The `CUSTOMER_PERMISSIONS` table is created and populated in the development database.

What is the best way to create and copy the `CUSTOMER_PERMISSIONS` table to the production database?

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_MARKET_PERMS
SELECT * FROM indeiso.dbo.CUSTOMER_MARKET_PERMS
```

returns

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_MARKET_PERMS
SELECT * FROM inukiso.dbo.CUSTOMER_MARKET_PERMS
Error at Command Line:668 Column:25
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am using Oracle 12 database system, and i am not sure why it is throwing this error

Comment: First, are you sure that you're using Oracle 12?  That would imply that you are using a private beta of the very most recent version of Oracle.  That seems unlikely to me but it's certainly possible.  Second, are you really talking about a separate database?  Or a separate schema in the same database?  Or, if you really are using Oracle 12, are you talking about a separate pluggable database inside your component database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with not using a query, and in case you happen to be using MSSQL Server, why not use the import/export wizard?

Right-click the database you want to export from, then select TASKS -> Export Data. From there, follow the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

on the prod server you can do a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_PERMISSIONS
SELECT * FROM [devserver].dbo.CUSTOMER_PERMISSIONS
```

Comment: That'd require a linked server to be setup.

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have two different Oracle databases? If so then you need to setup a database link between the two databases. If I were you I should first make sure that you from the production database can select the data in the development database. If you can that and the two tables are identical then I can't see way your statement is not working.